# Stack Overflow Developer Surveyをどう訳す？

Tags: 討議, 翻訳

翻訳に "Stack Overflow Developer Survey" という言葉が来ました。今までも調査はあったものの、訳されたことは無かったように記憶しています。この言葉は日本語として訳すべきか、これひと塊で固有名詞として訳さず置いておくべきか、どちらが良いでしょうか？

https://ja.traducir.win/string/10447

Answer (score 4, accepted):

英語版にアクセスするとバナー表示があるので、traducir.win に文字列が追加されたのもこれに合わせてでしょうかね。

[Take the 2019 Developer Survey now](https://stackoverflow.com/dev-survey/start?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=announcement-banner&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2019)

今回の調査が日本語版でも行われ、かつ調査内容(質問)も日本語であるなら適切な翻訳を考えてもいいのかもしれませんが、そうでなければ翻訳の優先度は下がると個人的には思います。

Comment: 確かに調査の本文が日本語かどうかは大きそうです。aki さんに chat で聞いてみます。

Comment: 調査の内容は英語だそうです。 https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48686574#48686574

Comment: とりあえず訳さずに置いておいて、今後必要になったら訳すので良さそうに思えたので、この回答を承認します。ありがとうございます :)